# notnull checking in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```
String uid = selenium.getTable("bc."+i+"."+0);

System.out.println(uid);

int bcid = Integer.parseInt(uid);

if(uid != "' '"){   

    selenium.type("bcname", s.getCell(0, i).getContents()); 

    }else{

     System.out.println("Not edited");  

   }
```

i need to check my 'uid' value is notnull.but it is not working,i dnt knw what is the problem.How can i check not null value ,pls help me

Comment: Do you want to check whether uid is not NULL or is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check whether the string is empty

```
if(!uid.isEmpty())
```